# Is there a "correct" file name for an .ics file?

Tags: icalendar

There are numerous implementations that default to near meaningless names (like "calendar.ics" "my appointment.ics") or no name at all. If it is in [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), I missed it. Is there another specification that is appropriate?

Is there a specification or authoritative best practice that says what the file name should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is one, on the caldav side it's mostly a generated UUID or something similar.

Quoting Caldav's [RFC 4791 - section 5.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-5.3.2):

> Clients populate calendar collections with calendar object resources.
> The URL for each calendar object resource is entirely **arbitrary** and
> does not need to bear a specific relationship to the calendar object
> resource's iCalendar properties or other metadata.  New calendar
> object resources MUST be created with a PUT request targeted at an
> unmapped URI.  A PUT request targeted at a mapped URI updates an
> existing calendar object resource.

This is an example bellow that section:

```
PUT /home/lisa/calendars/events/qwue23489.ics HTTP/1.1
   If-None-Match: *
   Host: cal.example.com
   Content-Type: text/calendar
   Content-Length: xxxx
   ...
```

Even when you are sending an .ics file from Mac's calendar it just appends a date and time of the export to the name (`iCal-20200528-202500.ics`). So it can be whatever you want it to be.